# SQL: overcoming no ORDER BY in nested query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `t` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    date    TEXT,
    a       TEXT,
    b       TEXT
);
```

**Sample Data**

```
1|2015-06-15|a1 15|b1 15
2|2015-06-15|a2 15|b2 15
3|2015-06-16|a1 16|b1 16
4|2015-06-16|a2 16|b2 16
5|2015-06-17|a1 17|b1 17
6|2015-06-17|a2 17|b2 17
```

I want to select all values of `a` and `b` for the two latest dates in the table.

I want to do something like the following:

```
SELECT a,b FROM t WHERE date IN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2);
```

**Expected Output**

```
a1 17|b1 17
a2 17|b2 17
```

but you aren't allowed `ORDER BY` in a nested query.  How can this be done in a single query?

Comment: @ughai . . . That returns two rows, but not necessarily two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join` instead:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM t JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2) tt
     on t.date = tt.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT t.a,t.b FROM t 
join(SELECT DISTINCT date FROM t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2) q
on t.date=q.date
```